# How can I apply a class to a P tag created in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I am generating an element using p5.js.

How can I apply the `basic_font` class to this `p` element?

*.js (p5.js)

```
createElement('p', "Number of columns:").parent(div);
```

*.css

```
.basic_font {
    color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: `document.createElement` doesn't support the second parameter being used like that.

Comment: Nor does an element have a parent method. We have no idea what library you are using to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Consider adding the class to the element `pElement.classList.add('.basic_font')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classList` to add a class (in this case basic_font) and its styles to your element. parent is the parent element.

```js
var el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerHTML = 'Number of Columns';
el.classList.add('basic_font');
parent.appendChild(el);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

You can also use setAttribute on `class`.

```
el.setAttribute('class', 'basic_font');
```

<del>Keep in mind also that the way you added innerHTML to the element is incorrect. You must specify it separately.</del>

You mentioned you are using p5.js which appears to have a `class()` method for adding classes to created elements. See https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element. Try using it as follows:

```
createElement('p', "Number of columns:").parent(div).class('basic_font');
```

Comment: There is too much we don't know about the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox He asked how he can add a class and its style to a P element. The tags are javascript, html, and CSS. This is valid Javascript and it will work for OP.

Comment: I don’t disagree, but the OP hasn’t made it clear they want to use “vanilla” js

Comment: @evolutionxbox why would we assume they want to use a certain library when they haven't specified or even hinted at it?

Comment: @Penguin good question. The OP, didn't use `document`, used a non-standard second param on `createElement`, and used a non-standard method `parent()`. We've asked for clarification, but the OP has not responded.

Comment: @evolutionbox fair, but to me it just looks like he doesnt understand the variables and methods

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I forgot to mention I am using a p5.js due to having animation on my website, and when looking into how to label sliders, the example code used `createElement()`. Thank you for all your feedback.

Comment: @primitiveProgrammer See https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element for more information. There seems to be a ``class()`` method to add a class to the created element. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Thank you very much, again I should of stated this earlier but I was just so determined to fix the issue!